# Can mix up parameter query in SQL statement in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml

Not sure If I can use this ?-operator in a Mix Up SQL statement for parameter Query. Is there any rule on this? Or I must use ? operator all the way.

Thank

```
Example:

var allUsers = await db.QueryAsync("Select * From Customer Where CompanyName =?" + " AND Name like '" + txtBxName.Text + "%'", Company);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use parameters only for some strings, but that would be silly.

Appending `%` to a string can be done either in C#:

```
db.QueryAsync("SELECT ... ? ... Name LIKE ?", Company, txtBxName.Text + "%");
```

or in SQL:

```
db.QueryAsync("SELECT ... ? ... Name LIKE ? || '%'", Company, txtBxName.Text);
```

Comment: Just to confirm. If ? operator is used. This means the ENTIRE sql statement is parameter query and I cannot mix some part in SQL using normal way to pass in parameter and other parts using ? to pass parameters.

Comment: I said that it **is** possible, it's just unlikely that there is a good reason to do it.